# Launching a Windows Forms application from a Windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, exe

My problem: Can I run an exe (a Windows Forms application) from a Windows service? If so, how?

Comment: [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use **System.Diagnostics.Process.Start** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx to start an executable process.

But please keep in mind that services are expected (and most often does) run in their own context. For example the service would start running as soon as windows startes and even before any user is logged on. If your service decides to start the exe when no one is logged in, you will not see the UI of the form

Answer (score 0):

First for all you should say what versions of windows, for vista and later here there [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx), for xp you should check "allow desktop interaction" in service property, but anyway it's considered as bad and insecure practice, so by any chance you should try to avoid that.